# Reorganize and aggregate data by count and timerange

Tags: mysql, pandas

I'm thinking an efficient way to reorganize and aggregate data by the time range by using pandas or sql directly.

For example, I have some data in MySQL database recording jobs on a node like this:

```
job_id, time_start, time_end
1,      00:00,      04:00
2,      02:00,      05:00
3,      06:00,      07:00
```

I want to apply some operations and get a table like this(time are split within the range of earliest job start and latest job end, count means in that range, how many jobs are active):

```
time_start, time_end, count of active jobs
00:00,      02:00,    1
02:00,      04:00,    2
04:00,      05:00,    1
06:00,      07:00,    1
```

or a table like this(count means the number of active jobs, time_duration means how long does this node has `count` of jobs active):

```
time_duration, count of active jobs
4hrs,           1
2hrs,           2
```

All I can think of is maintain a dictionary variable and go through all rows in the raw table.

Comment: It would b helpful if you could describe what this data represents and the purpose of the new tables... the difference between the new tables and the original... and what "count" means... count of what?

Comment: @BooberBunz, edited. Thanks!

Comment: The ranges appear to be arbitrary. How are they determined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1a4039/18)**

Assumption: You will use `date/timestamp` column instead of just strings and it might behave incorrectly if proper format is not used.

Required Query

```
select t3.range_start, t3.range_end,count(*) as count_of_act_job
from your_table t1
cross join
(
    select time_start as range_start ,time_end as range_end from ( select
    t2.*, @next as time_end , @next := time_start
    from
    (   select time_start from your_table
        union 
        select time_end as time_start from your_table
    ) t2
    , (select @next := null) var_init
    order by time_start desc
    ) sq
    where time_start<>time_end
) t3
where  t3.range_start>=t1.time_start and t3.range_end<=t1.time_end
group by t3.range_start,t3.range_end
order by range_start
```

Output:

```
+-------------+-----------+------------------+
| range_start | range_end | count_of_act_job |
+-------------+-----------+------------------+
| 00:00       | 02:00     |                1 |
| 02:00       | 04:00     |                2 |
| 04:00       | 05:00     |                1 |
| 06:00       | 07:00     |                1 |
+-------------+-----------+------------------+
```

## Explanation:

Step1: t2 query; union to get all the possible times.

```
select time_start from your_table
union 
select time_end as time_start from your_table;
```

Output

```
+------------+
| time_start |
+------------+
| 00:00      |
| 02:00      |
| 06:00      |
| 04:00      |
| 05:00      |
| 07:00      |
+------------+
```

Step2: t3 query; using variables to replicate `lead` function. It will give all possible combinations of Range.

```
select time_start as range_start ,time_end as range_end from ( select
t2.*, @next as time_end , @next := time_start
from
(   select time_start from your_table
    union 
    select time_end as time_start from your_table
) t2
, (select @next := null) var_init
order by time_start desc
) sq
where time_start<>time_end;
```

Output:

```
+-------------+-----------+
| range_start | range_end |
+-------------+-----------+
| 06:00       | 07:00     |
| 05:00       | 06:00     |
| 04:00       | 05:00     |
| 02:00       | 04:00     |
| 00:00       | 02:00     |
+-------------+-----------+
```

Step3. Get all distinct ranges by doing a cross join of your_table with t3. The where clause will filter unwanted records.

```
select t3.range_start, t3.range_end
from your_table t1
cross join
(
    select time_start as range_start ,time_end as range_end from ( select
    t2.*, @next as time_end , @next := time_start
    from
    (   select time_start from your_table
        union 
        select time_end as time_start from your_table
    ) t2
    , (select @next := null) var_init
    order by time_start desc
    ) sq
    where time_start<>time_end
) t3
where  t3.range_start>=t1.time_start and t3.range_end<=t1.time_end;
```

Output:

```
+-------------+-----------+
| range_start | range_end |
+-------------+-----------+
| 06:00       | 07:00     |
| 04:00       | 05:00     |
| 02:00       | 04:00     |
| 02:00       | 04:00     |
| 00:00       | 02:00     |
+-------------+-----------+
```

Step4. Use `Count(*)` after `Group By` to get the required result